# How to completely stop "Disk Not Ejected Properly" message?

Tags: macos, mojave, external-disk, ipod

I use my MBP to charge my iPod and regularly unplug it without ejecting first - perhaps my laptop is asleep or I changed nothing...

How can I stop this message?

[image: eject message]

I'm aware of the reason for the message and I've seen many questions here relating to stopping it appearing multiple times which is not my issue.

My question is can I turn it off completely?

I would be happy if the answer applied to all disks - not just iPod.

It bugs me as even if I have accepted the risk of just unplugging a disk, it is too late for the specific instance but will tell you **every time** you do so until the end of time. Afterwards.

Comment: If it's an old Classic, try locking it before you connect. Newer iOS based devices shouldn't need to be unmounted first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's one system-level notification you cannot disable without turning off Notifications entirely.

May I suggest you use a standalone charger? :)